# Writing a SASS mixin for 3d text with depth

Tags: sass

I have the following SASS mixin in my project

```
@mixin text_3d($color){
  color: $color; 
  text-shadow:   0 3px 0 darken($color, 14%),
         0 4px 0 darken($color, 15%),
         0 5px 0 darken($color, 16%),
         0 6px 0 darken($color, 17%),
        3px 8px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        3px 8px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}
```

I would like to replace the multiple "text-shadow" lines to a loop but I can't figure out how to do it. 
In pseudo-code :

```
@mixin text_3d($color, $depth){
  color: $color; 
  text-shadow:   
       @for $i from 0 through $depth {
           0 ($i+3)px 0 darken($color, $i+14%), 
       }

    3px 8px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    3px 8px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}
```

But I keep getting errors as if I can't place the @for there.

```
(Line 143: Invalid CSS after "  text-shadow:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@for $i from 0 ...")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@mixin threedshadow($color, $depth) {
  $all: ();
  @for $i from 1 through $depth {
    $all: append($all, append($i*1px $i*1px 0, darken($color, $i+14%)), comma);
  $all: append($all, 3px 8px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.1), comma);
  $all: append($all, 3px 8px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
  text-shadow: $all
  }
}

h1 {
  @include threedshadow(#fff, 5);
}
```

You were having a similar but not identical [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937503/multiple-values-for-one-property-with-variable-argument-lists-in-sass) that I was, the trick is to save the values for `text-shadow` in a variable outside the `@for` loop, and then `append()` them on with a `comma`.

You may also want to tweak the shadow that you left outside of the loop in your example so that it matches up with the `$depth`.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/aCDko)

Comment: I see you are using some other syntax than what I have. 
http://sass-lang.com/
Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: I used .sass, which forgoes semicolons and brackets in favor of whitespace. I'll update the answer to .scss which is more like vanilla css.

Comment: Wow! amazing. I've tried reading about a solution for this for a couple of hours, but couldn't find it anywhere. May I ask how do you know this? What are your resources?

Comment: I just read the official [docs](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html), guy!