# SASS Text Shadow With Alpha

Tags: css, sass, rgba

I'm relatively new to SASS and am trying to convert the following code into a SASS mixin to prevent having to write it all longhand. Can anyone help me? I've been working on it for two days and can't seem to get it to work, but like I said, I'm new to SASS. Here's the longhand CSS I'd like to change to a mixin:

```
text-shadow: 
1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.50), 
2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.49), 
3px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.48), 
4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.47), 
5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.46), 
6px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.45), 
7px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.44), 
8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.43) 
[...and so on to about 50]
```

I was able to get a mixin that would generate the text-shadow depth, but when I try to adjust the alpha, I get warnings because the value goes beyond 1 and the opacity needs a value of between 0 and 1.

And here's the code I tried (which compiled fine, but outputted nothing):

```
@mixin render-shadow($depth){
    $longshadow: ();
    @for $i from 1 through $depth {
        @while $alpha > 0 {
            $alpha: 0.50;
            $longshadow: $longshadow, $i*1px $i*1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,$alpha);
        }
    }
    text-shadow: $longshadow;
}
```

I also tried:

```
@mixin render-shadow($depth){
    $longshadow: ();
    @for $i from 1 through $depth {
        $longshadow: $longshadow, $i*1px $i*1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,($i - 0.01));
    }
    text-shadow: $longshadow;
}
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Syntax error: Alpha channel 1.99 must be between 0 and 1 for `rgba'
```

And:

```
@mixin render-shadow($depth){
    $longshadow: ();
    @for $i from 1 through $depth {
        $alpha: 0.50;
        $longshadow: $longshadow, $i*1px $i*1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,($alpha - 0.01));
    }
    text-shadow: $longshadow;
}
```

Which rendered the shadow but at a constant 0.49 opacity instead of incrementing to 0.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  I don't see a mixin here, nor do I see values falling outside of 0 and 1.

Comment: That's the longhand CSS code. I'd like to convert that to a mixin so I don't have to type it all out.

Comment: So have you *tried* anything?  SO isn't a code writing service, you're supposed to show what you've tried and why it didn't work... you know, show that you've made an effort.

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, but they were nowhere near correct. I thought posting them would just confuse the issue since I know I'm going to need to start from scratch. I'm just looking for some pointers on how to use SASS in this way. I'm not looking for someone to write my code. I'd be fine if someone just pointed me in the direction of correct SASS documentation for this type of thing. If it helps, I tried modifying the technique at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975097/writing-a-sass-mixin-for-3d-text-with-depth.

Comment: @cimmanon: I've added my attempts per your request so that you can see what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you aren't effectively calculating the alpha changes.

In your first example, by the time you get to the 50th iteration, `($i - 0.01)` is evaluating to 49.01.  In your second example, you were never updating your `$alpha` variable, so it was always evaluating to `.49`.

You'll want to perform a calculation more like this:

```
@mixin render-shadow($depth, $alpha-start: 1, $alpha-step: 0.01) {
    $longshadow: ();
    @for $i from 1 through $depth {
        $longshadow: append($longshadow, $i * 1px $i * 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, $alpha-start - ($i * $alpha-step)));
    }
    text-shadow: $longshadow;
}

.foo {
  @include render-shadow(50);
}
```

You will need to check to make sure that `$alpha-start - ($i * $alpha-step)` is not falling outside of 0 and 1 (which is entirely possible, depending on how many shadows you create and what your alpha start/step values are).

It is worth noting that as of Sass 3.4, alpha values are clamped (ie. you won't get this error anymore anyway).

Comment: Thank you so much cimmanon! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for explaining what I was doing wrong. If I could vote-up you I would, but I don't have sufficient reputation yet. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for this, like so:

```
$i: 0.50;
$px: 1;

@while $i > 0 {
  .selector {
    text-shadow: #{$px}px #{$px}px 0 rgba(0,0,0, $i);
  }
  $i: $i - 0.01;
  $px: $px + 1;
}
```

Or if you want to use a mixin, you can do it like this:

```
@mixin text-shadow($start, $px) {
  text-shadow: #{$px}px #{$px}px 0 rgba(0,0,0, $start);
}

$i: 0.50;
$px: 1;

@while $i > 0 {
  .selector {
    @include text-shadow($i, $px);
  }
  $i: $i - 0.01;
  $px: $px + 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your quick response. I got it to mostly work with the code above, however instead of a single "text-shadow" with multiple shadows attached, I'm getting multiple "text-shadows" like ' text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);' etc. instead of ' text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);' etc.