# SASS: loop inside properties

Tags: css, sass

I want to generate multiple values for a single property:

```
background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle, $primary 10%, transparent 10%),
    radial-gradient(circle, $primary 10%, transparent 10%),
    radial-gradient(circle, $primary 10%, transparent 10%),
    radial-gradient(circle, $primary 10%, transparent 10%);
```

I tried to achieve this by doing this:

```
background-image:
    @for $i from 1 to 5 {
        radial-gradient(circle, $primary 10%, transparent 10%),
    }
```

However, this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a SASS mixin for 3d text with depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975097/writing-a-sass-mixin-for-3d-text-with-depth)

Comment: Radial Gradient takes only one declaration not four as you have showing, all you need to know here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-radial-gradient/. You're repeating the same gradient four times, in other words.

Comment: @NathanielFlick, I am afraid you are wrong. Once I change the position of eash, I will have multiple circles at different locations.

Comment: No, first you will need to define those four circles in their own position: circle at top right, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare a variable before and use it after all your logic.

BTW, you can play also with the `$i` and colors like `$color#{$i}`.

```
.gradient{
  $color1: #000;
  $color2: #fff;
  $background: null;

  @for $i from 1 through 4 {
      $background: $background radial-gradient(circle, $color1 10%, $color2 10%)#{if($i !=4, ',', '')};
  }

  background-image: $background;
}
```

Comment: Rad! Worked like a charm.