# Sass: loop to set multiple values for a single property

Tags: sass

I referenced another topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937503/multiple-values-for-one-property-with-variable-argument-lists-in-sass), but to no avail.

Essentially am attempting to apply text shadows the length of half of a button, I had it working previously with static values, but wanted to change it to dynamically adjust to the size of the button, with the option to have the shadow on the left/right side of the icon.

```
$size: 80px;
$color-primary: ######;

@mixin shadow($clr: $color-primary, $perc: 15%, $dir: 'right') {
  $all: ();
  @for $i from 1 through strip-units($size/2) {

    $shadow: "#{$i}px #{$i}px darken($clr, unquote($perc))";

    @if $dir == 'left'{
        $all: append($all, append(unquote(-$shadow), comma))
    } @else {
        $all: append($all, append(unquote($shadow), comma))
    }
 }
 text-shadow: $all;
} 

button {
  background-color: $color-primary;
  color: $color-secondary;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: ($size/1.5);
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: $size;
  height: $size;
  line-height: ($size + 4px)
  @include shadow($color-primary);
}
```

Can someone help me get this mixin working? I feel like I am close.

Edit:

Sorry, I should have clarified; there don't appear to be any errors popping up at all, it just doesn't generate the shadow.

[Here is the live sample](http://codepen.io/wjramos/pen/CuoDG)

And the CSS output when the mixin is called is supposed to look like:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px darken(######, 15%),
             2px 2x darken(######, 15%), [etc.]
```

Or with a negative first value if 'left' is chosen for $dir

There are no errors, and I just checked (using the separator unquote(','))and it compiles to:

```
button {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px darken(#e74c3c, 15%) , 
                 2px 2px darken(#e74c3c, 15%) , 
                 [etc.]
}
```

So, it seems to be generating whitespace before the comma, but I don't know if that is the real issue

Using comma as the separator outputs the string 'comma' instead of the symbol, preceded by a space

Comment: So what doesn't work exactly?  It would help if there weren't multiple syntax errors and undefined mixins/variables we have to fix first.

Comment: Sorry, I added a link to the actual code above. I also added a sample of the compiled code

Comment: Did you try looking at the compiled result?  Maybe validating it?

Comment: Yes I did, it compiled successfully with no errors, and one thing stood out: a space before the trailing comma. I'm not sure how to get rid of it though. I added a sample of the compiled result above

Comment: When I look at the compiled result, it looks like this: `text-shadow: 1px 1px darken(#e74c3c, 15%) comma 2px 2px darken(#e74c3c, 15%) comma`.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry: the above compilation is the result of using "," instead of comma, because I was receiving that same output

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 problems going on here.

- You're turning everything into a string via interpolation (functions like darken must be passed a color and a percentage, not strings)
- You're appending the string "comma" into the list.

So, what you want is something more like this:

```
@mixin long-shadow($clr: $color-primary, $perc: 15%, $dir: 'right') {
    $all: ();
    @for $i from 1 through strip-units($size/2) {
      $all: append($all, if($dir == 'left', $i * 1px, $i * -1px) $i * 1px darken($clr, $perc), comma);
    }

    text-shadow: $all;
}
```

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/eAvKh

Comment: That explains a lot, I guess I misunderstood the effect unquote() has on a string.

Thank you for your solution! it works perfectly (after switching the negative and positive 1px)